# I am importing FormGroup in my feature module and it throws error in Angular4 multiple modules structure

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

## App module

```
app.module.ts

   `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup } from'@angular/forms';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

   /*Routing Module*/
   import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

  /*Core Module*/
   import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

  /*Shared Module*/
  import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';

  /*Featured Module*/
  import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
  import { LandingModule } from './landing/landing.module';

  @NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormGroup,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      SharedModule.forRoot(),
      LandingModule,
      LoginModule,
      CoreModule.forRoot(),
      AppRoutingModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule
   ],
   declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

## Shared Module

```
shared.module.ts

`import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
 import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ CommonModule, MaterialModule, FlexLayoutModule], 
declarations: [  ], 
exports:      [ CommonModule, MaterialModule, FlexLayoutModule]
 })

export class SharedModule { 
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

## Feature Module

```
 landing.module.ts

   `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators }    from '@angular/forms';
    import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';

    import { LandingRoutingModule } from './landing-routing.module';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        FormGroup,
        SharedModule,
        LandingRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [HomeComponent, RegisterComponent]
    })
    export class LandingModule { }
```

Then inside my RegisterComponent I tried using FormGroup and I get error on console saying 
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Please could anybody tell me the correct way to import modules in multiple modules

## Core module

```
`import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { StoreService } from './store.service';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [],
    exports:      []
  })
  export class CoreModule {
    constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
          throw new Error(
            'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
      }

      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [ HttpService, StoreService ]
        };
    }
  }`
```

## app-routing.module

```
`import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}`
```

And also the correct way to do Lazy loading.Thankyou

Comment: The error is fixed for formgroup , I had missed importing ReactiveformsModule in my feature module, could anybody help as to where to place formsModule , ReactiveformsModule in Core or in shared so that again it is not required to import in feature module and aslo the correct way to Lazy load my feature module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use **`FormGroup`** inside any module.Remove from Feature Module.

You can directly import in the component iteself

```
NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,       
        SharedModule,
        LandingRoutingModule
      ],
 declarations: [HomeComponent, RegisterComponent]
```

Comment: After adding in declaration it throws Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: After correcting in my landing module it throws Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.Could you help me as to where to correctly import as I am using multiple modules, thanks

Comment: can you reproduce somehwre?

Comment: I have placed the code in plunker but it is not working could you please have a look https://plnkr.co/edit/Xm1zt1kfz8fJa2PmkiSx?p=preview

Comment: Hi that error is fixed I had missed ReactiveformsModule in imports of Feature Module , could you please help me with lazy loading my feature module